# HTML form variable value not passing over to PHP class in MVC configuration

Tags: php, javascript, html

Before I start - I've read a lot about passing variables from HTML pages using  and using $_GET['name'].

I have an HTML form with a list, where depending on the selection (the values which are received from a table in MSSQL DB), a second list should be populated depending on the value of the first list:
E.g. Interest - make the selection in the list of Interests, and depending on 1 / 2 / 3 , will filter a list of SubInterest in a table Subinterest on the same DB.  This list is in a HTML form (my View in the Model-Controller-View ; a javascript Alert,shows the value selection, as well as the value being shown in the URL

When I use $_GET[] in  my PHP file (controller in the MVC),the value is shown as null.

Anyone has any ideas what may be wrong?

Code snippets below

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function getID()
    {
    var idVal = document.getElementById("interestDrop").value;  
    window.location.assign("cInterests.php?id=" + idVal);
    alert(idVal);
    }
</script>
.
.
.
Interests 1: 
    <form name="formInterest1" action="cInterests.php" method="get">
    <select id="interestDrop" onchange="getID()"> 
        <option value="">Please select interest</option>
            <?php foreach($interests as $interest):?>
                <option value="<?php echo $interest['InterestID'];?>">
                <?php echo $interest['Interest'];?>
                </option>
            <?php endforeach;?>

    </select>               
    </form>
```

THE PHP FILE's BEGINNING

```
<?php 
      $idVal = $_GET['id']; // is this '' or "" ?
class cInterests extends CI_Controller
{   
    .
    .
}
```

When I debug in his file, the $idVal show NULL...

Comment: So you using codeigniter ? Can i see cInterests.php ?

Answer (score 0):

#### Edit: read the question properly :)

Since you are using CodeIgniter, you should use

```
$idVal = $this->input->get('id');
```

#### Addition:

Also, beware of the config, you have to have this in your config:

```
$config['enable_query_strings'] = true;
```

(query strings should be set to true for this to work)

Answer (score 0):

your target url doesn't seem to work properly.
the MVC's Action URL should look like..

> index.php/Interests/someaction

same in javascript location

```
window.location.assign("/Interests/someaction?id=" + idVal);
//or this is basic MVC route uri
window.location.assign("/Interests/otheract/" + idVal);
```

your controller

```
<?php
//DO NOT insert any logic code outside class/function
class Interests extends CI_Controller {

    public function someaction()
    {
        $id = $this->input->get('id');
        var_dump($id);
    }

    public function otheract($id)
    {
        var_dump($id);
    }
}
?>
```

i would suggest you to learn [What is a Controller](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/controllers.html)  and [URI Routing](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html)